# Android : Display Markers in MapActivity

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

This code below currently shows location of device. I am getting JSON from URL, and parsing it below. I want to display this as Markers in my MapActivity. I am getting  java.lang.NullPointerException on mMap.addMarket(_markeroptions).

I am getting JSON data, that part is working, just not able to display it on Map. Your guidance will be helpful.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

// Add stDisplayListView code here
JSONArray jsonArray;
String json_string;

// End stDisplayListView



public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleMap mMap;


Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

Marker doctorLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
   // int x =_st.jsonArray.length();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }



    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}




    /**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  //  int count = _st.doctorAdapter.getCount();
   // int i =1;
    json_string = getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_DTA");
    try {
        int count =0 ;
        //jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string);
        int _id;
        String _doctorname;
        String _doclat;
        String _doclong;
        //List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        while(count < jsonArray.length())
        {
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            _id = JO.getInt("id");
            _doctorname = JO.getString("doctorname");
            _doclat = JO.getString("latitude");
            _doclong = JO.getString("longitude");

            count++;

            Double d = Double.parseDouble(_doclat);
            Double e = Double.parseDouble(_doclong);

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(d,e);
            //mMap = googleMap;

            MarkerOptions _markeroptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng);
            mMap.addMarker(_markeroptions);




        }

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    // int a = _st.json_string.length();
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }



    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);


    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    //ParseJSONdata parseJSONdata = new ParseJSONdata();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission was granted.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        //You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
```

Comment: Just look at the code. You assign mMap *after* you use it. Easy fix.

Comment: So 'MarkerOptions _markeroptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng);
                mMap = googleMap;' should be a fix?

Comment: Move the whole marker code after the whole map initialization

Comment: I changed it to 
MarkerOptions _markeroptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng);
        //mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.addMarker(_markeroptions);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID); as you said..now I can see the Marker. But only one. I have 2 in my array.

Answer (score 0):

```
When onMapReady() method is call you used map Object without initialization and after you initialize, so then have return null pointer.

 mMap = googleMap; //Map initialize by this line 
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


this code put above try catch in onMapReady() method and run your code.
```